not enough signers
pip install solana==0.35.1            pip install solders==0.21.0
def send_transaction_via_rpc(private_key_base58, transaction_base64, latest_blockhash):
try:
# Decode the Base58 private key and create a Keypair
private_key = base58.b58decode(private_key_base58)
keypair = Keypair.from_bytes(private_key)
    # Decode the transaction
    transaction_bytes = base64.b64decode(transaction_base64)
    transaction = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(transaction_bytes)

    # Ensure that account_keys[0] in the transaction matches our own public key
    print(f"Account keys in the transaction: {transaction.message.account_keys}")
    print(f"Local Keypair public key: {keypair.pubkey()}")

    if keypair.pubkey() != transaction.message.account_keys[0]:
        print(f"Error: Keypair public key does not match the account key in the transaction")
        return None

    # Replace the blockhash
    recent_blockhash = Hash.from_string(latest_blockhash)

    # Create a new transaction message, ensuring address_table_lookups are provided
    new_message = MessageV0(
        header=transaction.message.header,
        account_keys=transaction.message.account_keys,
        recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash,
        instructions=transaction.message.instructions,
        address_table_lookups=transaction.message.address_table_lookups if hasattr(transaction.message, 'address_table_lookups') else []  # Default to an empty list
    )

    # Create a new transaction
    new_transaction = VersionedTransaction(new_message, [])

    # Sign the transaction
    new_transaction.sign([keypair])  # Ensure only your key signs the transaction
    print(f"Transaction signed successfully, public key: {keypair.pubkey()}")

    # Send the transaction
    response = client.send_transaction(new_transaction)
    print(f"Transaction sent successfully, response: {response}")
    return response
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Transaction failed: {e}")
    return None

